# How to build a Play!Framework 2 modules that is version independent?

Tags: module, playframework-2.0

I've built a Play!Framework 2 module using the well explained article from http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=363 but the module fails if I change the PlayFramework version (via an update for example).

Is there a way to make the module "version independent" ?

Comment: When you say you change the Play version, do you mean e.g. 2.1.0 to 2.2.1, or 2.1.0 to 2.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific. Does it fail to build? Does it fail at runtime? Does it fail to be resolved as a dependency?

If it's the last problem, check this out: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html